# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser - <body> only with a rename of a div ID

Tags: php, html, parsing

I am using PHP Simple HTML DOM parser to good effect with this simple bit of code:-

```
<?php
include_once('./simple_html_dom.php');
$oldhtml = file_get_html('./6.html');
$newhtml = $oldhtml->find("body", 0);
echo $newhtml->innertext;
$oldhtml->clear();
$newhtml->clear();
?>
```

(I appreciate that in its current form it can be improved!)

But there is one thing I need to change but I cannot work out the correct syntax to make it work. The resulting document is near perfect for my needs except that it starts with

```
<div id="container">
```

And I would like to simply rename that ID to something else. I could live with just `<div>` or ideally something like `<div id "six">`

Any pointers will be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: <div id "container"> or <div id= "container"> ?????? whats ur correct output , please be more clear for what u r looking in ur answer

Comment: @sree: -infinity for `u r` and the like. Stop being lazy and use proper language. This is NOT myspace/facebook/sms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$oldhtml = file_get_html('http://stackoverflow.com/');
$oldhtml->find('div[id=custom-header]', 0)->id= 'six';
die($oldhtml);
```

Comment: Hi and thanks.
I have tried that already and I get "<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function find() on a non-object in...."

Comment: Perfect when I add back the line
<?php
include_once('./simple_html_dom.php');
$oldhtml = file_get_html('./6.html');
$oldhtml->find('div[id=container]', 0)->id= 'six';
$oldhtml = $oldhtml->find("body", 0);
echo $oldhtml->innertext;
$oldhtml->clear();
?>

Comment: Do you have any problem now?